# lower_bound in c++ stl returns an iterator even when the element is not present. How to avoid this?

Tags: c++

With

```
int arr[]={1,2,3,5,6,7};
```

using `lower_bound(arr,arr+6,4)` returns an iterator to `5`. How to make sure that it returns an index only when the element is present?

Comment: Is the goal to get a binary search that returns an iterator?

Comment: complexity of find()?

Comment: @HarveyAndrews It is O(N).

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes with the lowest index at which the element occurs

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But it returns only true or false

Comment: The example code on the [cppreference page for `lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) seems to have exactly what you need.

Comment: @HarveyAndrews You're right. I assumed there was a standard binary search equivalent to `std::find` but it doesn't appear so. Looks like the best bet might be to check that the returned iterator's referred value is the one you asked for after the fact.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::lower_bound` is what you want, you just need to add a condition to your check.  To see if `4` is in the array you would just use

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,5,6,7}; 
auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 4)
if (it != std::end(arr) && *it == 4) // && short circuts so *it == 4 wont be done unless it is valid
    std::cout << "4 found";
else
    std::cout << "4 not found";
```

Answer (score 5):

[std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) *always* returns an iterator - no way around that.

Specifically, it returns "Iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than value, or last if no such element is found". (And testing for "last" to determine "not found" is easy).

That's the definition of the algorithm. If that suits your needs, use it. If not, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `std::lower_bound( begin, end, value )` does not return `end` when element `value` is not found because it makes it more generic. For example if you want to find sequence in sorted container that contain 3, 4 or 5s can be written as:

```
auto b = std::lower_bound( begin, end, 3 );
auto e = std::upper_bound( b, end, 5 );
```

after this range `[b,e)` will have elements 3,4,5s if any or empty range in which case `b == e`. In this case if there are no elements with value 3 in container (but 4 or 5) and it would work you want it  will not find them. On another side adapting `lower_bound()` for your case (put additional check or use `std::equal_range()` and compare both iterators) is trivial.